# VB.Net Encryption File increase byte array x7

Tags: vb.net, file, memory, encryption

I can encrypt files 100 mb or smaller but I transport file bytes to array memory usage increase x7 and program pass 2 gb memory limit

Example Test.rar size 100 mb

After Encryption

Program use 700 mb ram and if passed 300 mb or higher result SystemOutOfMemory Exception

```
    ' AesCryptoServiceProvider


    Dim aes As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
    aes.BlockSize = 128
    aes.KeySize = 256


    aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12K2K2K2K2K2K2K212K2K2K2K2K2K2K2")
    aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12K2K2K2K2K2K2K2")

    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

    ' Convert string to byte array
    Dim src As Byte() = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes("C:\TestFolder\Test.rar")


    ' encryption
    Using enc As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor()
        Dim dest As Byte() = enc.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length)










        Dim ms As New MemoryStream 'Create New Memory Space

        Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor, mode:=CryptoStreamMode.Write) 'Write İn Ms
        cs.Write(dest, 0, dest.Length)
        cs.Close()

        Dim ss() As Byte = ms.ToArray




        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("C:\TestFolder\TestCopy.rar", ss, True)



        ms.Dispose()
        cs.Dispose()
        src = Nothing
        ss = Nothing
        dest = Nothing
```

Comment: A constant IV completely misses the point of an IV, which is to be different for each message. Also a key is binary, so you can't use UTF-8 to encode it (hex and base64) work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes, you're reading the whole file into memory and then encrypting the whole thing in one go. You don't need to do that - you can do the whole thing in a streaming approach.

You need three streams:

- One stream to read input from
- One stream to write to disk
- A crypto stream wrapping that second stream

Then just use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy from the input stream to the crypto stream.

In C# it would look like this:

```
using (var input = File.OpenRead(@"C:\TestFolder\Test.rar"))
using (var output = File.Create(@"C:\TestFolder\Test.rar.encrypted"))
using (var crypto = New CryptoStream(output, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    input.CopyTo(crypto);
}
```

Hopefully you can convert that to VB easily enough.

Comment: You need to save the IV, otherwise it won't be possible to decrypt the first block.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Sure, but IMO that's outside the scope of the question, which is about avoiding having too much data in memory.

Comment: cannot copy crypto stream because file bytes passed application memory and increase x7

Comment: @MuzluPide: Did you actually try the code I presented? That code doesn't read the whole file into memory at the same time, so it should be absolutely fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet i try it when file copyto cryptostream filled all memory

Comment: @MuzluPide: it really shouldn't. Could you edit your new code into the question? (After the current code.)